# What directory tree does `R CMD check` see when it runs the tests?

Tags: r, unit-testing, package, devtools

I'm wondering what files and folders are visible when `R CMD` is running the tests under the `tests/testthat` folder?

I've noticed that the test command can see the `tests` directory, but that the `R` directory and the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE` files are not visible.

Here is a sample unittest file that I placed under `tests/testthat/test-whereami.R`:

```
test_that("where am i", {
  expect_true(file.exists("../../R"))
  expect_true(file.exists("../../tests"))
  expect_true(file.exists("../../DESCRIPTION"))
  expect_true(file.exists("../testthat.R"))
})
```

When I run the tests using the `devtools::test()`, all tests pass (as they should). But when I `check` the package, the first and third tests fail; only files/folders inside `tests/` seem to be visible.

I want to know what exactly is visible to the testing tool? I couldn't figure out a way to see exactly what files and folders are visible, I've tried:

- placing a `browser()` inside the test file
- placing a `print(list.files())` inside the test suite
- place a `write.table(list.files("../.."), file = "aaaa.txt")`

Using these approaches, running `devtools::test()` did show me what it sees, but that wasn't very useful because `devtools::test()` passes all the tests anyway.  When running `check`, the things I tried did not produce anything (no print statements/no files were written).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By placing `stop(list.dirs('..')` in a test file and running `devtools::check()`. The output shows a "tests" folder and a "<package-name" folder which contains the source. The tests are running in the "tests" folder.